# Is it possible to buy a prop of one of the "bitcoins" you often see in the pictures?

Tags: physical-coins

Is it possible to buy a prop of one of the "bitcoins" you often see in pictures? Does anyone actually make physical "bitcoins?" I collect weird iconic things.

Comment: What do you mean by "licensed"?

Comment: This shouldn't be closed as "Unclear what is being asked". There was just the misconception that Physical Coins would have to be licensed. I edited for clarity and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

[Casascius](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Casascius_physical_bitcoins) made physical coins with a private key attached (hidden with similar technology to scratch lottery cards). They were [shut down](http://www.theverge.com/2013/12/13/5207256/casascius-maker-of-shiny-physical-bitcoins-shut-down-by-treasury) in 2013 by the USA Treasury.

There are other companies who make [physical Bitcoins](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=physical%20bitcoins&rlz=1C9BKJA_enAU590AU590&oq=physical%20bitcoins&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en-US) but I cannot vouch for the services personally.

If it's memorabilia then a "used" coin is no problem. However it was possible to use non-polar solvent through an insulin syringe to peel back the Casascius safety seal to see the private keys *without showing signs of tampering*. This means it may be an issue to pay for ฿1 and find later your coins were stolen since your private key is known. If you buy a coin with ฿ associated with a Casascius coin private key I'd immediately transfer it to a "safe" address.

Comment: Also, to further this answer, those original Casascius coins fetch a pretty penny on eBay.  Don't expect to get any of those "props" for cheap because they aren't fake.